# What does $x \equiv_m y$ mean?

Tags: notation, congruences

I just stumbled over $x \equiv_m y$ and I am not quite sure what it means. Is it a short form for $x \equiv y \pmod m$?

Comment: I have seen it used for the meaning you suggest

Comment: This notation has the advantage that you can chain it easily.